# Jquery Making a click dynamically

Tags: jquery, syntax, concatenation, each

I want to make some clicks with Jquery dynamically onLoad of a page. I found how :

```
$("#pdt1").trigger("click");
```

I have part of the id into my session display into a string like that "1,3,7" and i want to generate some clicks like that :

```
$("#pdt1").trigger("click");
$("#pdt3").trigger("click");
$("#pdt7").trigger("click");
```

So i have write that in Jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //Getting my string of Ids
        var mesId = $('#<%= selectedID.ClientID %>').val();
        //Cut my string into an array
        var subId = mesId.split(',');
        //Send a click for each id
        $(subId).each(function (event) {
            $('#pdt'+ this).trigger("click");
        });
    });
```

And obviously, that don't work. I am sure that i get my ids and cut them properly. What i'm not sure is about the each function, and the concatenation. Anyone know how make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds terrible practice.

Comment: I do not deny that. I have few day of Jquery practice, if you can suggest a better way, i will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.each` like below,

```
$.each(subId, function (index, value) {
    $('#pdt'+ value ).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Vega. I try your code, and for the .each and concatenation, i'm sure now that everything works. I have others problems, from the onload probably.